# play sticky avatar video on web page

Tags: javascript, html, web, video

i need javascript (or any other method) to play avatar video like in this page https://www.gocompu.net/wwwjava/index.html

Notes :in this page when you open it you well see talking character in fixed position even if you scroll page (bottom-right) start to talk when you click on play button

it's just a video in MP4/WEBM Format with transparent background or chroma green back ground with play/close button

Comment: could you clarify the question?

Comment: in this page (https://www.gocompu.net/wwwjava/index.html) when you open it you well see talking character in fixed position even if you scroll page (bottom-right) start to talk when you click on play button

it's just a video in MP4/WEBM Format with transparent background or chroma green back ground with play/close button ,how to make something like this with javascript